# Does Lumia 1020 support 4G in india?

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020

Lumia 1020 supports LTE Bands 18, 8, 3, 1, 7 . Does those support in India? Can we tweak it to work in India?

Comment: It depends of your mobile operator, what's yours ?

Comment: I have no 4G sim, but Vodafone, Jio and Airtel provides 4G to india! i want to know if any of these 4G sims would work or not. cant buy without properly knowing abt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some data about the LTE bands used by major Indian telecom operators

- Reliance Jio support LTE Bands 3,5 and 40.
- Airtel India offers LTE on Bands 1,3,8 and 40.
- No offcial information on Vodofone but this [website](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/LTE-frequency-bands-and-4G-LTE-phones-in-INDIA.html) here claims Vodofone provides 4G services at 1800MHz(Band 3).
- I could not find any info on other operators such as Aircel.

Based on these values I suppose there should be no trouble in getting the 4G services working on Lumia 1020.

---

**Regarding Varients**

According to GSMArena, Nokia Lumia 1020 has two varients in 4G it seems. The RM-875 and RM-877 which supports different LTE Bands. Here are the details,

> - **RM-875** - LTE band 1(2100), 3(1800), 7(2600), 8(900), 20(800)
> - **RM-877** - LTE band 2(1900), 4(1700/2100), 5(850), 17(700)

Based on the above data it would be best to buy Lumia 1020 RM-875 model as Band 3 is used by all of the Indian Telecom providers.

---

**Regarding Jio**

Jio would work on both Bands. However in three states namely Bihar, Punjab and JK Jio has no Band 3 LTE. Take that into note if you are living in these 3 states.

---

**References**

1. [Jio - Radio frequency summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jio#Radio_frequency_summary)
2. [Airtel - Radio frequency summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airtel_India#Radio_frequency_summary)
3. [LTE Frequenc Bands in India](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/LTE-frequency-bands-and-4G-LTE-phones-in-INDIA.html)
4. [Nokia Lumia 1020 - GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_lumia_1020-5506.php)

Comment: mine's 875! thanks a lot! you're a lifesaver!